# Sharing java objects in Rhino Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, rhino

Let me first start with admitting that I am a noob in JavaScript. So the question might not be very sound at the basics and might lack enough information to help me.

### Background

My organisation has an internal Eclipse based IDE for JavaScript. All we have to do is write scripts in JavaScript and directly execute them. My guess is it uses Rhino since I have seen it in the stack trace of some exceptions.

My code runs across 3 ".js" files.

Script-1: Declare global variables and instantiate them as Java objects

```
importClass(java.util.HashMap);
var hmTCResult = new HashMap();
```

Script-2: Perform some actions using the global variables from Script-1

```
Script-2.prototype.run = function() {
hmTCResult.put("Result", "Fail");
};

changeStatus = function(strStatus){
hmTCResult.put("Result", strStatus);
};
```

Script-3: Call function in Script-2 which uses the global variables

```
changeStatus("Pass")
```

### Problem Definition

When from Script-3 I call the function in Script-2 it doesn't seem pick the instance variables and my function fails i.e. I get an exception "hmTCResult not set to the instance of an object." Please note that the the same variable hmTCResult works well in Script 1.

I have done some reading of the Scope and the Context in JavaScript but haven't been able to break through it, since I don't see it explicitly in the IDE.

I will be happy to provide more information if needed.

Comment: I don't think there are any "Java" objects shared which matter for you. Please show us the relevant parts of your code, i.e. the declaration of that function in script 2, the invocation in script 3 and point to the variables which you want to have used but which don't

Comment: Would you provide us some code?

Comment: Question updated with the code. Im sorry I cannot provide the complete code. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I have no experience with Java/Rhino but `Script-2` is not a valid JavaScript identifier. Name it `Script2` or `Script_2`.

Comment: Thanks Ian, but the mentioned script names are for illustration only. The actual Script names are very much valid.

Comment: Seems like `hmTCResult` is not really a global variable as like `changeStatus` is. Maybe your scripting environment (I don't know how your three script files are run) executes everything in a file-wide scope. Try removing the `var` keyword or assign `hmTCResult` explicitly to your global object.

Comment: Thanks Bergi for the reply. I tried removing the var keyword, without luck.  I did Google and find that I could use window.hmTCResult to explicitly add it to the global object. However since this isn't JavaScript which can be executed in Browser I am not sure if this will work. Any other way I can assign it to assign it to the global object ?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine, just juggle your scopes and get prototype search set up:

```
Context cx = Context.enter();
try {
    // Cache and reuse:
    ScriptableObject sealedSharedScope = cx.initStandardObjects(null,
            true);
    // Force the LiveConnect stuff to be loaded.
    String loadMe = "RegExp; getClass; java; Packages; JavaAdapter;";
    cx.evaluateString(sealedSharedScope, loadMe, "preLoadLazyLoad", 0,
            null);

    cx.evaluateString(sealedSharedScope, "varInRoot = 'blah';",
            "setVarInRoot", 0, null);

    // here you can put more cx.evaluateString calls to set up your
    // environment (eg. hmTCResult)

    // now connect a throw-away new scope into the hierarchy, with local
    // vars:
    Scriptable scope = cx.newObject(sealedSharedScope);
    // ensure that definitions in the root scope are found
    scope.setPrototype(sealedSharedScope);
    // ensure that new global variables are created in this scope (don't
    // use
    // var for them!)
    scope.setParentScope(null);

    cx.evaluateString(scope, "localVar = varInRoot;", "mySource", 0,
            null);
    assertEquals("blah", scope.get("localVar", scope).toString());
    // new var not in root:
    assertEquals(ScriptableObject.NOT_FOUND,
            sealedSharedScope.get("localVar", scope));
} finally {
    Context.exit();
}
```

Beware that scope.get doesn't search the prototype chain - gotta do that yourself!

Scopes are independent of Context and survive Context.exit().

Answer (score 0):

To evaluate a js script in Java the following operation may be performed

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByMimeType( "text/javascript" );
Bindings bindings = engine.getBindings( ScriptContext.GLOBAL_SCOPE );
bindings.put( "varname", ... );
bindings.put( ... );
engine.put( ScriptEngine.FILENAME, script.toString());
engine.eval( new FileReader( script ));
```

If the 3 scripts are loaded within the same engine/bindings it's ok, but if the engine is newly allocated for executing script3, the context has been cleared.

This post is not really an answer but too long to be a comment.

Comment: Thanks Aubin. As I have mentioned my tool, though Eclipse based,  functions more like a JavaScript IDE. I do not see Java code in the tool.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand that. I have retagged your question by removing Java since it not apply.

Comment: Aubin, I disagree. If you see my question I am using Java classes within JavaScript. So the tag Java is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

My guess, without more information, and assuming your modified transcripts are absolutely correct, is that your scripts are being run in separate scopes, all with the global scope as a parent.

As such, my guess is that the reason `changeStatus` works in the third script is because there is no `var` declaration for it. Thus, absent other configuration, this will be defined as a variable in the top-level, or global, scope, that is shared across the three scripts.

My guess is that the reason `hmTCResult` does *not* work is that it is declared with the keyword `var`, indicating a local variable. If all scripts were running in the top-level scope, this would define a variable on the global object. But if each script runs in its own scope, this would define a variable only in the scope of script 1. You wouldn't see the problem in the scope of script 2, because no one is executing the code in script 2 until script 3 executes.